# how to use gpg signing key on a remote server?

Tags: linux, ssh, gnupg

Is there a way of using gpg key in a remote server for signing by gpg program(command line tool) on linux?

I am using gpg for signing binaries on localhost with test keys. Now I want to use the same type of keys accessed by a server. I am looking for a realization just by changing the gpg tool's arguments.

Comment: probably, but now you've opened a massive can of worms by needing to have your private key either accessible so the remote server can access it for the signing operation, or having the private key duplicated in multiple locations (local + remote).

Comment: I dont want to read the private key but do the signing operation on server. however you are right that security level of the key decreases to the level of the user that will be accessed via ssh.

Comment: the private key HAS to be accessible for the signing operation. no private key, no signing operation.

Comment: as far as i know gpg can also do it with opengpg smard card which will be the last step. and as far as i know the computer does not(and can not) access the private key during this operation

Comment: "as far as i know ..." What you 'know' is wrong. A digital signature is created using the file itself and your private key, so that anyone who has a copy of your public key may validate the signature. In a sense, it's the opposite of when a file gets encrypted to be sent to you - that uses the public key and the file so that you can decrypt it with your private key.

Comment: @ataman is right regarding the computer accessing the private key: the file hash is sent to the smart card, which has its own crypto processor, signs the hash and sends the signature back to the computer. The key indeed never leaves the card.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with `OpenSSH>=6.7` and `GnuPG>=2.1.1`

OpenSSH 6.7 introduced unix socket forwarding which will used to forward the gpg-agent socket. And GnuPG 2.1 got rid of the `secring.gpg` delegating private key management to `gpg-agent`. This avoids having to keep the private key on the remote machine.

First you'll want to set up an extra-socket on the local client. Add this line to your `gpg-agent.conf`

```
extra-socket /path/to/extra-socket
```

Restart your `gpg-agent`

```
pkill gpg-agent
gpg-connect-agent /bye
```

Open an ssh connection to the remote server and forward the servers gpg-agent socket back to the client (make sure `gpg-agent` isn`t already running on the remote)

```
ssh -R ${GNUPGHOME:-~/.gnupg}/S.gpg-agent:/path/to/extra-socket remote-server
```

*Note: `GNUPGHOME` refers to the home folder of gnupg on the* ***remote***. *If it is different from the local `GNUPGHOME`, you'll have to adapt this.*

You should now be able to sign/encrypt on the remote server, provided it has your public key in the keyring.

*Note: You may need to add a graphical pinentry (qt,gtk) to your clients `gpg-agent.conf`, I'm not sure the curses one will work.*

By default, OpenSSH will not remove the the forwarded socket on the server upon closing the connection. This will prevent OpenSSH to create the socket during the next connection. If you have access to the servers `sshd_config` you may add the following line

```
StreamLocalBindUnlink yes
```

or remove it in you logout script (`.zlogout`, `.bash_logout`, ...)

```
rm ${GNUPGHOME:-~/gnupg}/S.gpg-agent
```

Further information can be found on this GnuPG wiki page. https://wiki.gnupg.org/AgentForwarding

Comment: I'm trying this (OpenSSH 7.2, gpg 2.1.13), but ssh fails to set up the forwarding. It says: debug1: Remote connections from /home/scripty/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:-2 forwarded to local address /home/dfaure/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent-extra:-2 -- is the "-2" expected in this output ?

Comment: (the server has older versions though: OpenSSH_6.0p1, gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.19, maybe that's the issue.)

Comment: Yes, both client and server need the required version of OpenSSH. You might be able to use on older version of GnuPG on the server but then you have to keep the private key on the server as well which defeats the point.

Comment: I am also getting "-2" but it works. Maybe you should check if the debug logs success for failure. On my system, it logged success in another entry close to the "-2" one

Comment: maybe you could also link https://wiki.gnupg.org/AgentForwarding which explains in great detail to how to achieve this

Comment: Thanks. I've added the link. I don't think that page existed when I answered the question.